# maven resourse pluggin error

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, filenotfoundexception

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project : Error loading property file 'D:\....
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This occurs when I import a git project in Eclipse. I tried `mvn install`, `mvn package`, but it gives the same error. And then I update my project as well, but still the same issue. How to solve this?

This is with `-e`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project anuragropu: Error loading
property file 'D:\.\main\environments\${env}.properties' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-
resources) on project anuragropu: Error loading property file 'D:\...\src\main\environments\${env}.properties'
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error loading property file 'D:\..\src\main\environments\${env}.
properties'
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Error loading property file 'D:\..\src\main\environme
nts\${env}.properties'
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.loadProperties(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.getDefaultFilterWrappers(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:205)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:301)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\..\src\main\environments\${env}.properties
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.PropertyUtils.loadPropertyFile(PropertyUtils.java:65)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.loadProperties(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:284)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: run with `-e` and post the exception stacktrace

Comment: Based on the error stack it looks like the Git project is referring to a property file, on the D drive which might not be path of the project on your machine. A full debug maven build would indicate the path whcih you can check further.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your "env" property can't be resolved by the Maven. Check if there is a profile or something that has to be explicitly activated to define "env" property. It's common practice to define such properties in additional profiles.

In order to activate profile from command line use -P:

```
mvn -Pprod install
```

Finally you can define the property explicitly running the mvn command like this:

```
mvn -Denv=prod install
```

In case of Eclipse click RMB on the project, select "Maven->Select Maven Profiles..." from the menu and choose all profiles which should be activated while project is being built.

To check if there are any profiles available use:

```
mvn help:all-profiles
```

Comment: Error loading property file 'D:\..\src\main\environments\${env}.properties' (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources:default-testResources:process-test-resources)           then i get this error